# Create a filter in a page template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using Realto theme for wordpress I am wondering if I am on the correct path.  I need to display properties from a city. So I decide to create a page template to add the location

This are the default arguments but I dont know how to filter the results by city

```
$args = array(
        'numberposts'     => '',
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'offset'          => 0,
        'cat'        =>  '',
        'orderby'         => 'date',
        'order'           => 'DESC',
        'include'         => '',
        'exclude'         => '',
        'meta_key'        => '',
        'meta_value'      => '',
        'post_type'       => 'property',
        'post_mime_type'  => '',
        'post_parent'     => '',
        'paged'             => $paged,
        'post_status'     => 'publish'
    );
```

I tried adding

```
'locations' => 'MYCITY'
```

but it didnt work

This is an example of the search results when I search by city, so I am basing my arguments on this.

```
/?post_type=property&search_keyword=&locations=MYCITY&property_type=proyectos&beds=&baths=&status=&min-price=&max-price=
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `locations` is a custom field? Maybe this works:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'property',
    'meta_key' => 'locations',
    'meta_value' => 'MYCITY'
);

?>
```

Visit http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters for more details.